# Insert values in D3 Calendar visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Need help in showing attendence value in each cell of D3 Calender visualization. I am new to D3 and kind of stuck in this step. Appreciate as much help on this.

Sample Date used for visualization

```
 Date   Station Group   Attendance  Absent  PTO
 2010-07-19 C   GH  57  10  0
 2010-07-20 C   EF  58  10  1
 2010-09-21 A   GH  6   1   1
 2010-09-20 A   IJ  6   1   2
 2010-09-17 A   AB  6   1   3
```

HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>




    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .day {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: #ccc;
    }

    .month {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .RdYlGn .q10-11{fill:rgb(165,0,38)}
    .RdYlGn .q9-11{fill:rgb(215,48,39)}
    .RdYlGn .q8-11{fill:rgb(244,109,67)}
    .RdYlGn .q7-11{fill:rgb(253,174,97)}
    .RdYlGn .q6-11{fill:rgb(254,224,139)}
    .RdYlGn .q5-11{fill:rgb(255,255,191)}
    .RdYlGn .q4-11{fill:rgb(217,239,139)}
    .RdYlGn .q3-11{fill:rgb(166,217,106)}
    .RdYlGn .q2-11{fill:rgb(102,189,99)}
    .RdYlGn .q1-11{fill:rgb(26,152,80)}
    .RdYlGn .q0-11{fill:rgb(0,104,55)}


    .chart rect {
      fill: steelblue;
    }

    .chart text {
      fill: white;
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      text-anchor: end;
    }

    </style>

    <body>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-time-format.v2.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    //For Selecting Distinct Year from Date field for drop down
    d3.csv("station.csv", function(error, csv) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date.split("-")[0]; })
        .sortKeys(d3.descending)
      .rollup(function(v) { return {
        total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.Attendance; })
      }; })
        .entries(csv);

     var dropdown = d3.select('body')
      .append('select')
        .attr('class','select')
        .attr('id','year_dropdown')
        .on('change', Year_change_Del); 


    var options = dropdown.selectAll('option')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('option')
            .text(function (d) { return d.key; });
    });

    //For Selecting Distinct Year from Date field for drop down
    d3.csv("station.csv", function(error, csv) {
      if (error) throw error;

      var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Station; })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
      .rollup(function(v) { return {
        total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.Attendance; })
      }; })
        .entries(csv);

     var dropdown = d3.select('body')
      .append('select')
        .attr('class','select')
        .attr('id','station_dropdown')
        .on('change', Year_change_Del); 


    var options = dropdown.selectAll('option')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('option')
            .text(function (d) { return d.key; });
    });

    var width = 1450,
        height = 190,
        cellSize = 25; // cell size


    var percent = d3.format(".1%"),
        format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

    var color = d3.scale.quantize()
        .domain([-.05, .50])
        .range(d3.range(11).map(function(d) { return "q" + d + "-11"; }));

    var month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var week_days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];

    function Year_change_Del(){

    d3.selectAll('svg').remove();
    d3.select(".day").remove();

    Year_Change_Create();
    };

    function Year_Change_Create() {

    var station_selection = d3.select('#station_dropdown').property('value');

    var year_selection = eval(d3.select('#year_dropdown').property('value')),
            year_start = eval(d3.select('#year_dropdown').property('value')) -2  ,
            year_end = eval(d3.select('#year_dropdown').property('value')) +1   ;   

    //alert(year_end);


    var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
        .data(d3.range(year_start, year_end).reverse())
      .enter().append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-45," + cellSize * 3.5 + ")rotate(-90)")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

    for (var i=0; i<7; i++)
    {    
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-15," + cellSize*(i+1) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dy", "-.25em")
        .text(function(d) { return week_days[i]; }); 
     }


    var rect = svg.selectAll(".day")
        .data(function(d) { return d3.time.days(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
        .enter().append("g");

    var newrect = rect.append("rect")
            .attr("id",function(d) { return d.getFullYear(d) + "," + d3.time.weekOfYear(d) * cellSize + "," + d.getDay() * cellSize; })
            .attr("class", "day")
            .attr("width", cellSize)
            .attr("height", cellSize)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d3.time.weekOfYear(d) * cellSize; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return d.getDay() * cellSize; })
            .datum(format);

        newrect.append("title")
                .text(function(d) { return d ; });


    var newrect1 = rect.append("text")
                .attr("class", "day")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return d3.time.weekOfYear(d) * cellSize ; })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return d.getDay() * cellSize; })
                .attr("dy", "15px")
                .attr("dx", "5px")
                .style({"font-size":"8px","z-index":"999999999"})
                .style("text-anchor", "left")   
                .text(function(d) { return d ; });



    // to add month name on top of graph - month name not getting aligned properly

    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data(month)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (((i+1) * ((width -50)/12))) + ",0)"; });

    legend.append("text")
       .attr("class", function(d,i){ return month[i] })
       .style("text-anchor", "end")
       .attr("dy", "-.45em")
       .text(function(d,i){ return month[i] });

    svg.selectAll(".month")
        .data(function(d) { return d3.time.months(new Date(d, 0, 1), new Date(d + 1, 0, 1)); })
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "month")
        .attr("d", monthPath);  

    d3.csv("station.csv", function(csv) {
    data = csv;
    dataset = datafilter(data);

        data=d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Absent * 100) / d[0].Attendance / 100; })
        .map(dataset);//console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      newrect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data[d]); })
        .select("title")
          .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + percent(data[d]); });     

    function datafilter(d){
    data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.Station  == station_selection;});
    return data;};

    }); 

    d3.csv("station.csv", function(csv) {
    data = csv;
    dataset = datafilter(data);

            d3.csv("station.csv", function(csv) {
    data = csv;
    dataset = datafilter(data);

        data=d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Absent * 100) / d[0].Attendance / 100; })
        .entries(dataset);//console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
        .select("text")
          .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + percent(data[d]); });   

    function datafilter(d){
    data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.Station  == station_selection;});
    return data;};

    });




        function monthPath(t0) {
      var t1 = new Date(t0.getFullYear(), t0.getMonth() + 1, 0),
          d0 = t0.getDay(), w0 = d3.time.weekOfYear(t0),
          d1 = t1.getDay(), w1 = d3.time.weekOfYear(t1);
      return "M" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "," + d0 * cellSize
          + "H" + w0 * cellSize + "V" + 7 * cellSize
          + "H" + w1 * cellSize + "V" + (d1 + 1) * cellSize
          + "H" + (w1 + 1) * cellSize + "V" + 0
          + "H" + (w0 + 1) * cellSize + "Z";
    }   
    };

    var formatTime = function(input){
        var dateParse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
        var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y");
        return dateFormat(dateParse(input));
    };  

    var formatTime = function(input){
        var dateParse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
        var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%u");
        return dateFormat(dateParse(input));
    };  



</Script>
```

The first D3.csv creates the chart and does the coloring and even the tooltip is working. I am trying to get the data to be inserted into each cell from the second D3.csv. But this is not working. Can someone guide me on this.

```
   d3.csv("station.csv", function(csv) {
    data = csv;
    dataset = datafilter(data);

        data=d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Absent * 100) / d[0].Attendance / 100; })
        .map(dataset);//console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      newrect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
          .attr("class", function(d) { return "day " + color(data[d]); })
        .select("title")
          .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + percent(data[d]); });     

    function datafilter(d){
    data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.Station  == station_selection;});
    return data;};

    }); 

    d3.csv("station.csv", function(csv) {
    data = csv;
    dataset = datafilter(data);

            d3.csv("station.csv", function(csv) {
    data = csv;
    dataset = datafilter(data);

        data=d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Date; })
        .rollup(function(d) { return (d[0].Absent * 100) / d[0].Attendance / 100; })
        .entries(dataset);//console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      rect.filter(function(d) { return d in data; })
        .select("text")
          .text(function(d) { return d + ": " + percent(data[d]); });   

    function datafilter(d){
    data = data.filter(function(d) { return d.Station  == station_selection;});
    return data;};

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Who wants the d3 calendar with dates?

Here is an example fiddle created by me.

```js
var cellSize = 17, // cell size
    width = cellSize * 8,
    height = cellSize * 9,
    firstDayOfEachMonth = getFirstDayOfEachMonth(2013);
   
var day = d3.time.format("%w"),
    myday = d3.time.format("%d"),
    week = d3.time.format("%U"),
 monthName = d3.time.format("%B");
    percent = d3.format(".1%"),
    format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

var svg = d3.select("#calendars").selectAll("svg")
    .data(firstDayOfEachMonth)
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
 // Just centering the month here
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - cellSize * 7 - 1) + "," + ((height - cellSize * 6) / 2) + ")");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cellSize * 3.5 + ", -6)")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return monthName(d); });

var rect = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(function(d) { return getDaysInMonth(d); })
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "mygroup")
    //.attr("width", cellSize)
    //.attr("height", cellSize)
    //.attr("x", function(d) { return day(d) * cellSize; })
    //.attr("y", function(d) { return (week(d) - getFirstWeekOfMonth(d)) * cellSize; })
    //.on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).attr("class", "hovered")}) 
    //.on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")}) 
   //.on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).attr("class", "")}) 
    // format is a function - a formatter configured to use the format specified above (format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");)
 // datum will execute the function to set the data for each item in the dataset - in this case, every day in the year.
 //.datum(format);

rect.append("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return getDaysInMonth(d); })
  //.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "day")
    .attr("width", cellSize)
    .attr("height", cellSize)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return day(d) * cellSize; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (week(d) - getFirstWeekOfMonth(d)) * cellSize; })
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).attr("class", "hovered")}) 
    //.on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")}) 
   .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).attr("class", "")}) 
    // format is a function - a formatter configured to use the format specified above (format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");)
 // datum will execute the function to set the data for each item in the dataset - in this case, every day in the year.
 .datum(format);

rect.append("text")
  //.text(function(d) { return d; })
  .text(function(d) { return myday(d)})
 .attr("x", function(d) { return day(d) * cellSize + 4; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return (week(d) - getFirstWeekOfMonth(d)) * cellSize + 12; })
    
rect.append("title")
    //  This will display the formatted date for each day in the year when hovered (title attribute)
 .text(function(d) { return d; });
 
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "2910px");

function getDaysInYear(year) {
 return d3.time.days(new Date(year, 0, 1), new Date(year + 1, 0, 1));
}

function getFirstDayOfEachMonth(year) {
 return d3.time.months(new Date(year, 0, 1), new Date(year + 1, 0, 1));
}

function getDaysInMonth(firstDayOfMonth) {
 return d3.time.days(firstDayOfMonth, new Date(firstDayOfMonth.getFullYear(), firstDayOfMonth.getMonth() + 1, 1));
}

function getFirstWeekOfMonth(day) {
 // TODO: stop using this.  It's wasteful because it gets executed for every day of every month.
 //  We should only do this once per month.  The problem is with referencing data throughout a month.
 //  Perhaps use a closure - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076553/combining-parent-and-nested-data-with-d3-js
 //  also, the "each" reference in - http://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/d3-selections/
 return week(new Date(day.getFullYear(), day.getMonth(), 1));
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.day {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.month {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

#calendars rect {
  fill: #ffffff;
  stroke: #bbbbbb;
}

#calendars rect.hovered {
  fill: #f0f8ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendars"></div>
```